# How to add an edit text on a button

Tags: android, button

I was wondering how to have the user be able to edit the text on a button in Android programming? I tried to put the edit text on top of the button but it is not working. How should I do this?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve will cause touch conflicts. if you click on button, it will open editor, if tou click on editor it will perform click.

Comment: Question is too broad. Depends on your UI. Show a screenshot of what is required.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `EditText` that is styled to look like a button.

Comment: One doubt, when he will click on the view, will it open the editor or will it click the button?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one way you can accomplish this is to have an EditText view right above the button you wish to change the text.
Then grab the text from the editText and apply it to the button.

Comment: what do you mean?